# How do I convert a string of a python dictionary to JSON object? json.loads() gives me a double quote error every time

Tags: python, json, parsing, type-conversion

I have this as a string:

```
{{
            "intent": "catalog_search",
            "id": 1,
            "dependency": [],
            "args": {{
                "text": "Could you please retrieve all table assets scanned before 1 hour?"
            }}
        }}
```

When I apply json.loads() to it, I get the error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)". What gives? All of the keys clearly have double quotes, is my formatting wrong in some way?

I thought the issue might be the double curly brackets at the start and end, but I got the same result when I removed them.

Comment: `{{` is not valid in JSON. Everything inside curly braces has to be `"key": value`

Comment: You don't just have `{{` at the start and end, you also have them after `"args":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the double braces need to be changed to single braces. This is valid:

```
{
    "intent": "catalog_search",
    "id": 1,
    "dependency": [],
    "args": {
        "text": "Could you please retrieve all table assets scanned before 1 hour?"
    }
}
```